# How does one locate all git log messages in the git object database?

Tags: git, logging, commit-message

Using git cat-file I can look at objects in the Key-value store but I am only interested in log messages. How do I filter out those?

Comment: You use `git log`. You should specify why you need to examine the git database and not use the API provided.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a slightly broken git repository, migrated using git-svn. There is no head or refs, therefore git log fails. I need to retrieve the logs in some other way, ie by accessing the object database directly.

Comment: for commit in $(cat all.git.object.file); do git cat-file -t $commit; done | grep commit

Comment: Would the person who down voted this please bare in mind that I was recovering log messages from a corrupt git repository after migrating using git-svn. The log messages were there, but the git log command was not working. I had to find another way to retrieve the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Make a list of all git object ids. Then use `git cat-file -t` and `grep` to filter all commits